# Understanding co-relation between multiple for loops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I understand the general purpose of this code is to find the starting index of a  subarray within an array

```
public static int findArray(int[] array, int[] subArray) {
    int index = -1;
    arrayLoop:
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == subArray[0]) {
            for (int j = 1; j < subArray.length; j++) {
                if (i + j > array.length - 1 || array[i + j] != subArray[j]) continue arrayLoop;
                //System.out.println( i+j );
            }
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

MY problem is this line

```
if (i+j>array.length-1 || array[i+j]!=subArray[j])
```

I think the first condition works this way:(i+j) means going downwards through the first array with respect to the second array length and the addition checks if it greater than 1 array less than the length of second Array, my question is why so? and more explanation if I am wrong. thank you.

Comment: where does the subArray var comes from?

Comment: I edited is better for understanding now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first condition (`i + j > array.length - 1`) is to check the overflow of master array

  for eg. `master array = [1,2,3,4,5]  and subArray = [4,5,6,7]`

  Consider this case, your code will enter the logic `array[i] == subArray[0]` when it finds `4`. `[i=3 and j=0]` Now, you will be iterating over the subArray to check for each element. `[i=3 and j=1] to check 5`, when you reach `6`, Can you guess what should happen? If you think it needs to stop, you are right. At this point `i=3 and j=2`. So the condition `i + j > array.length - 1` ==> `5 > 4` will kick in and you exit out of loop. Hope that helps.
- The second condition is to check if the elements of subArray and master array are same.

Comment: thanks - But I cant understand where it checks if 5 is found in the subArray

Comment: the second condition, `array[i + j] != subArray[j]` what will it check when `i=3` and `j=1`?

Comment: in this case 5 is equal to 5 in the second array so it continues to the next step j+1?

Comment: Yes, `j` will be incremented till 2 and you'll reach `6` thats when the first condition kick in and throw us out.

Comment: My gratitude @ajc